# After warp is installed on the cloud server, the cloud server cannot be remotely connected after warp-CLI connect is run. Why?

Tags: cloudflare

warp website：https://developers.cloudflare.com/warp-client/get-started/linux
os: ubuntu 22.04
tool: xshell
address: shanghai china

I installed WARP by following the steps on the cloudflare website.

```bash
# Add cloudflare gpg key
sudo curl https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/pubkey.gpg | sudo gpg --yes --dearmor --output /usr/share/keyrings/cloudflare-warp-archive-keyring.gpg

# Add this repo to your apt repositories
sudo echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloudflare-warp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/ $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudflare-client.list

# Install
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cloudflare-warp
```

Then I run the following command：

```bash
1. warp-cli register
2. warp-cli connect
```

After running the second command, my server was disconnected.and then it couldn't connect.

**How can I deploy warp?**